# Hysteresis curves of a ferromagnet magnetized below saturation

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

I am confused about the qualitative behavior of ferromagnetic materials. Referencing the diagram below, I understand that magnetizing a ferromagnet from point A to point C (its saturation magnetization) will result in the shown hysteresis curve, where to demagnetize the material (go from C to E) requires a reversed field be applied. But what if the initial magnetization is less, e.g. from point A to B? Do you just end up on another hysteresis curve contained within the saturation curve as I have drawn? Is there any way to get information about this smaller curve given experimental data like coercivity and saturation magnetization?

[image]